# error calling webservice in tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, web

I have a web service running in tomcat and each time i call with from client i have this error

> Caused by: org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory$ConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.parsers.StandardParserConfiguration could not be instantiated: org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.

What is weird is that i can call webservice and it do what it should do,but the code in client cant continue because that error.

Example:
Method in webservice that print hello world
Method in client that call the webservice and after that print a hello world.

Client can call web service and web service print hello world,but client no

Comment: Here is very good and easy to follow Java web services tutorial with "Hello, World!" example: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks,but i know how to build a web service.. I dont know is how to resolve this error :\ Anyway i will read this again

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a conflict of XML library in your webapp?